# Remove functions through jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Here is the code:

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
        screenlarge();
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {
        screensmall();
    });
    function screenlarge()  {
      windowsize = $(window).width();
      if (windowsize < 1040) {
          $('#wrappernav').fadeOut("fast");
          $('#sidebar').fadeOut("fast");
          $('#wrappernavbg').fadeOut("fast");
          $('#navigationon').fadeIn("fast");
    }
    } 
    function screensmall()  {
      windowsize = $(window).width();
      if (windowsize >= 1040) {
          $('#wrappernav').fadeIn("fast");
          $('#sidebar').fadeIn("fast");
          $('#wrappernavbg').fadeIn("fast");
          $('#navigationon').fadeOut("fast");   
    }
    }
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#naviclosed').bind('click', function () {
        $('#wrappernav').fadeIn("fast");
        $('#sidebar').fadeIn("fast");
        $('#wrappernavbg').fadeIn("fast");
        $('#navigationon').fadeOut("fast");
    });
        $("#arrow").bind('click', function(){
        $('#wrappernav').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#sidebar').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#wrappernavbg').fadeOut("fast");
        $('#navigationon').fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

My question is how can I remove the `screenlarge()` and `screensmall()` when I press the `#arrow`, and add the functions again when I press the `#navigationon`.

Please do help!

Comment: You don't remove/add functions that way. I think what you might be after is using variables and adding some conditional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, merge `screenlarge` and `screensmall` into single function like `sreenSize`. Just for clarity.

To unbind the event, simply do

```
$(window).off('resize', screenSize);
```

If you have no other event handlers for 'resize' event, you can also do it like this:

```
$(window).off('resize');
```

Comment: @Yoosuf I'm glad it worked. Btw, you don't say 'remove'. You say 'unbind'. Opposite is 'bind'. You 'bind' a handler function to an event.

Comment: Ya, I just figured that out. Thanks again!